# Laravel toArray() still returning an object in DB::raw

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this code:

```
 $response['data'] = DB::table('customers')
                ->select(DB::raw('name,email,address1,address2,postalcode,state_region,country_code,phone,created_at'))
                ->where('user_id',"=",Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('name','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('address1',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('email','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('address2','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('city','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('postalcode','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('state_region','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('country_code','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orWhere('phone','like',"%$search_value%")
                ->orderBy('name', $order)
                ->limit($length)
                ->offset($start)
                ->get()->toArray();
```

The result of this one is this:

```
'data' => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[194]
          public 'name' => string '|Barbara User' (length=13)
          public 'email' => string 'email@email.com' (length=16)
          public 'address1' => string 'address aaddress' (length=17)
          public 'address2' => null
          public 'postalcode' => string '00000000' (length=10)
          public 'state_region' => string 'GA' (length=2)
          public 'country_code' => string 'US' (length=2)
          public 'phone' => string '12312312312' (length=10)
          public 'created_at' => string '2017-01-02 15:20:20' (length=19)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[201]
            public 'name' => string '|Barbara User' (length=13)
          public 'email' => string 'email@email.com' (length=16)
          public 'address1' => string 'address aaddress' (length=17)
          public 'address2' => null
          public 'postalcode' => string '00000000' (length=10)
          public 'state_region' => string 'GA' (length=2)
          public 'country_code' => string 'US' (length=2)
          public 'phone' => string '12312312312' (length=10)
          public 'created_at' => string '2017-01-02 15:20:20' (length=19)
    ....
```

As you can see, there is still an object in the result even if I already did a `toArray()`.

What seems to be the problem here?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call `toArray()` on a `Collection`, if the underlying items implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable` interface, the collection will attempt to call `toArray()` on each item. However, when you use the query builder, the result will be a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects, and `stdClass` objects are plain objects that do not implement that interface and do not have a `toArray()` method. Therefore, when you call `toArray()` on a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects, you will just get a plain array of the `stdClass` objects back.

If you instead use Eloquent, define a `Customer` model, and use that model to perform the query, your result will be a `Collection` of `Customer` models, and those models do implement the `Arrayable` interface. So, when you call `toArray()` on this `Collection`, it will call `toArray()` on each item in the `Collection`, and your result will be an array of arrays.

If, for some reason, you don't want to use Eloquent, you will need to manually convert the items from objects to arrays. You can do this easily with the `map` or `transform` methods on the `Collection`. Use `map` if you want to return a new `Collection` and leave the original one alone, or use `transform` if you just want to modify the original `Collection`.

```
$response['data'] = DB::table('customers')  
    // query conditions, etc
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return (array) $item;
    })
    ->all();
```

Comment: This is best answer hands down. I didn't know the collection attempts to call toArray() on each item.

Answer (score 3):

You are converting the collection to array, not each model specifically.

You could do something like this using Laravel's collection [->transform()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-transform) method:

```
    $response['data'] = DB::table('customers')
            ->select(DB::raw('name,email,address1,address2,postalcode,state_region,country_code,phone,created_at'))
            ->where('user_id',"=",Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('name','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('address1',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('email','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('address2','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('city','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('postalcode','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('state_region','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('country_code','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('phone','like',"%$search_value%")
            ->orderBy('name', $order)
            ->limit($length)
            ->offset($start)
            ->get();

    $response['data']->transform(function ($item) {
        // return $item->toArray(); // You could do this if you called the query with model
        return (array)$item; // This should work in your case 
    });
```

This way $response['data'] will be a collection (not array) of arrays. You could additionally do this:

```
$response['data']->toArray();
```

To convert the collection to array as well.

Comment: I am getting a `Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()` in your `$item->toArray();`

Comment: That is interesting. I tested similar code (called with Model instead of \DB::table()) and it worked. Then I assume Amit Gupta's answer should work.

Comment: If the query was performed using an Eloquent `Model`, there wouldn't be any need for this. Models implement the `Arrayable` interface, so calling `toArray()` on the `Collection` would automatically call `toArray()` on the individual items.

Answer (score 1):

You can type cast each object in the collection to an array as:

```
$response['data']->transform(function($x) {
   return (array) $x; 
})->toArray();
```

And the `toArray` gets you from the collection back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

`toArray` is changing the collection of objects into an array of objects, like it should. If you want the objects inside the collection to also be arrays, you need to first convert each object:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([...])->take(1)->get();

$array = $users->map(function($obj){
    return (array) $obj;
})->toArray();
```